# javac error: package com.myproject.planets does not exist

Tags: java

Lets consider such catalog structure:

```
C:\Tests>tree /F
C:.
│   GreetingsUniverse.java
│
└───planets
        Earth.java
        Jupiter.java
```

Earth and Jupiter has `com.myproject.planets package`, GreetingsUniverse has `com.myproject` package.

Javac fails to compile GreetingsUniverse.java

```
C:\Tests>javac -cp "C:\Tests\planets"  GreetingsUniverse.java
GreetingsUniverse.java:3: error: package com.myproject.planets does not exist
import com.myproject.planets.Earth;
                            ^
GreetingsUniverse.java:4: error: package com.myproject.planets does not exist
import com.myproject.planets.Jupiter;
                            ^
GreetingsUniverse.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        new Earth();
            ^
  symbol:   class Earth
  location: class GreetingsUniverse
GreetingsUniverse.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
        new Jupiter();
            ^
  symbol:   class Jupiter
  location: class GreetingsUniverse
4 errors
```

And another try:

```
C:\Tests>javac -cp "C:\Tests\planets\"  GreetingsUniverse.java
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Why it doesnt compile? Do classes must be placed in catalogs structure same as package? So Jupiter should be placed in C:\Tests\com\myproject\planets\Jupiter.java or there is some other problem?

Comment: It's simple: the directory structure should match the package structure. If a class is in the package `com.myproject.planets`, then its source file should be in the folder `com/myproject/planets`. The `cp` option is supposed to contain jar files and directories that are roots of package trees.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to have the “src” subdirectory in the project directory. Then, as per industry standard, create the “main\java” subdirectory. Then put directories inside that strictly correspond to the package structure (this is mandatory). Then, if you really want to compile from command line, specify your “src” directory with `-cp`:

```
C:.
└───src
    └───main
         └───java
               └───com
                   └───myproject
                       └───planets
                                  Jupiter.class
                                  Jupiter.java

c:\temp\project>javac -cp src\main\java src\main\java\com\myproject\planets\Jupiter.java
```

Note that package name must exactly match the path relative to the classpath, so in my example the package declaration is `package com.myproject.planets`, *not* `src.com.myproject.planets`. Failure to follow this will cause problems like yours.

If you have deep package structure like `jp.co.ourcompany.ourdepartment.ourproject.ourpackage.oursubpackage`, it may become troublesome to follow this rule, but there's no way around that, unfortunately.

Having sources inside “src\main\java” has the advantage of being supported by industry standard build tools such as Maven and Gradle. You don't even have to tell them where your sources are: convention over configuration and all that.

Comment: Best practice is to use the enterprise standard package structure like src/main/java, src/test/java, src/main/resources etc... which is achieved by using build tools like maven, gradle. These tools will take of our packaging and Compilation issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
c:\javac -cp c:\;c:\Tests\;c:\Tests\planets GreetingsUniverse.java
```